# Filter nonnull after mapToLong doesn't work

Tags: java, lambda, filter

my codes goes like this

```
class A {
    private Long b;

    public Long getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(Long b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a1 = new A();
        List<A> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(a1);
        list.stream().mapToLong(A::getB).filter(Objects::nonNull).sum();
    }
}
```

I want to filter null, but it doesn't work, and give me an NullPointerException.
If I filter before mapToLong, like

```
list.stream().filter(a -> a.getB()!=null).mapToLong(A::getB).sum();
```

It works well. I want to know why.

Answer (score 6):

`mapToLong` converts the `Long` into `long` - if it's `null` you will indeed get an exception.

You need to filter the `null`s ***before*** the conversion:

```
list.stream()
    .map(A::getB)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)   //filter the nulls first
    .mapToLong(Long::longValue) //then convert to primitive
    .sum();
```

Comment: In fact, I don't think that it addresses the OP requirement. If you compare the  working and not working example, we guess that the `null` comes from `A::getB` mapping not from `null A` elements in the original list.

Answer (score 3):

here

```
list.stream().mapToLong(A::getB).filter(Objects::nonNull).sum();
```

your are trying to convert to Long every B of your list then filter no nulls. Now you are trying to convert nulls because you have not filtered nulls yet. That throws NullPointerException.

here

```
list.stream().filter(a -> a.getB()!=null).mapToLong(A::getB).sum();
```

you are filtering no nulls then mapping and converting them to Long. Here are no nulls when your are trying to convert because you have already filtered them, so is no NullPointerException.

Answer (score 2):

You pass a `ToLongFunction` to `mapToLong` function and this is its signature

```
long applyAsLong(T value);
```

You pass the method reference `A::getB` - Here, it takes your `b` and returns it by *unboxing* it (converting from `Long` to primitive `long`). Since it is null, it results in a NPE.

By doing the filtering earlier, you avoid this situation from happening.

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Answer (score 2):

Why this code fails ?

```
list.stream().mapToLong(A::getB).filter(Objects::nonNull).sum();
```

Because streams operations are executed sequentially. So if for any element of the stream `A::getB` doesn't return a not null `Long`, an exception would be risen during the collect.

Why it succeeds ?

```
list.stream().filter(a -> a.getB()!=null).mapToLong(A::getB).sum();
```

Because `filter()` that is first executed removes the null elements resulting to the `a::getB` operations. 
So you add only not null elements in the stream collect.  So no exception. 
But the problem is that you perform twice the mapping `a::getB`. Duplicate and so helpless even if here it is not expensive (just a getter).
What you want is :

```
list.stream()       
    .map(A::getB) // return Stream<Long> that may contain null
    .filter(Objects::nonNull) // filter null elements
    .mapToLong(s->s) // map Long to long
    .sum(); // sum
```